# online azure code editor for bot is not working

Tags: node.js, azure, bots, azure-language-understanding

I'm working in azure online code editor from past 1 week, but today suddenly it is showing error that "There was an issue running a git operation. Please use the console to check the state of your repository."  and when i am checking status of my git it is not showing anything....[see error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQrgk.png)

ya sure @ David Makogon , previously when i am using editor it looks something like this   [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGqjN.png)  after this when i open online code editor i my repository looks like  this  [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VravI.png).
but from few days i'm getting problem  with it.. [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFeUo.png)    and  today it's showing me to add some git Url...[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3U2V.png)   and   i think there is some problem with git repository  not with code bcz bot is still working according to my old code not with updated code...  and i'm not able to see my online git  repository which i have already shown.

Comment: Please edit to include any code and errors here, in the question (vs a captured image). That said: I'm not sure if that will even help, since this is a git credentials issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was the same problem and it was already fixed by Microsoft.

Comment: sorry, but can you provide me any link where i can  find solution for it.

Comment: I made a support issue and just waited for two business day. I've not seen any link about it.